# python string replace and enumerate with regex

Tags: python, regex, replace, token, enumerate

I want to implement string convertor and enumerate(tokenizer) using regex.

if given data like this:

"2017-04-03 08:10:42 today news ...(some many strings)... location china alert(fog, 5), Nan, Nan, level(5), weather is cloudy traffic(today > yesterday) increase"

expect processed result format(token list):

```
['DATE', 'Plain', 'location', 'Alert', 'Nan', 'Level', 'WeatherCondition', 'TrafficCondition']
```

Using `re.finditer(regex, given_data, re.I)` can possible to extract matched regex but, I want to display everything as 'Plain' except the matching regex.

I also want to remove duplicate values ​​from the list(ex 'Plain', 'Nan').

Comment: What is 'plain' here ? I can't see 'plain' in your input string ... if your input says: (some many strings) and output says something which is not in the input then how come you expect a solution here ? Give exact input, possibly 2 sets of input and 2 sets of output... unless you can verbally explain it better

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman 'Plain' is data that does not match the regex in the given data, such as today news ...(some many strings) in input data. if regex is 'traffic\(\w+\s?>/s?\w+\)' then result will be ['Plain', 'TrafficCondition']. Thanks to comment^^

Comment: btw, is that what you want ? https://regex101.com/r/EZ1mCQ/2

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman I want to separate the data through certain regular expressions, because of the input data is not always the same pattern. I want to make matched list and then compare keyword(regex group name) which is include or not.

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman First i reference this [site](http://effbot.org/zone/xml-scanner.htm) but, I can't make decision. Thanks for guide with your regex!